# Change class type at runtime

Tags: java

I have two classes (let's call them `A` and `B`), both inheriting from a common superclass (`C`).

Let's say I need to build a `List` of `C`s. My problem is that, depending on the data received by `C`'s constructor I need to put an `A` or `B` object inside the list.

Is there a way to do this from inside `C`'s constructor? Or, alternatively, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: This smells. You may be facing this problem because your class design is not that good. Normally, a class does not determine what type it is itself. There may be an underlying problem.

Comment: @Sjoerd I've never had a formal education on class design, so what you say may be the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a good place to use a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  Basically, create a class CFactory with a static method that has a return type of C.  That method can then decide to create either an A or a B and return that.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as Factory Pattern.

**Factory Pattern:**
In simple words, if we have a super class and n sub-classes, and based on data provided, we have to return the object of one of the sub-classes, we use a factory pattern.

Your implementation will look something like:

```
public class C {
//methods
}// End of class

public class A extends C {
//methods
}// End of class

public class B extends C {
//methods
}// End of class

public class CFactory {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         CFactory factory = new CFactory();
         factory.getObjects(args[0]);
     }
     public C getObjects(String type) {
         if (type.equals("A"))
             return new A();
         else if(type.equals("B"))
             return new B();
         else
             return null;
     }
}// End of class
```

Checkout example here:

http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/factory_pattern.htm

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this from C's constructor. You could create a factory method in C which creates an A or B depending on the data received:

```
class C {
   public final static C newInstance(Object data) {
        if (inspect(data)) {
            return new A(data);
        }
        return new B(data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do it from inside C's constructor?  Move whatever logic determines which type to instantiate to somewhere else, and just create the concrete type there?

Comment: Because the data received by C's constructor will fill the class members

Comment: @klez: You can make a constructor in `A` and `B` that calls C's constructor with the same signature using `super(arg1, arg2, etc)`

Comment: @klez:  However, you're the one determining what data goes into C's constructor.  That's not an answer.

Comment: I meant he can call A() or B() (or C()) somewhere else.  The factory pattern answer below is basically what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

an abstract factory method should help you which decides which implementation of C to use

```
public abstract class CFactory{
    public abstract C createCObject(data...){
        if (something) {
             return new A();
        }else{
            return new B();
        }
    }
}
```

then you can build List by using the abstract factory method...

hope this helped...

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not create an A or a B object from C's constructor.

You can create an A or a B from a static method in C. Or, you could create some factory class which does this.