# Change class from one to another at run time

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, extends

I have a situation in a project that I'm contributing to in which in a plugin system, a specific class is instantiated and overloaded functions are executed in it. I want to use 2 different groups of functions depending on a condition that is configured by the user. As a result, I need to switch between 2 classes at run-time.

I tried, in the constructor, setting the class of one function to another function

`a.class = b.class;`

But it turns out in Java, classes are final and cannot be changed

`error: cannot assign a value to final variable class`

I also tried using some ideas presented here:

[Change class type at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415623/change-class-type-at-runtime)

But they don't really solve this problem.

`EntryPoint.java`

```
public class EntryPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new a().the_func());
    }
}
```

`a.java`

```
public class a {
    public a() {
        a.class = b.class;
    }

    public int the_func() {
        return 22;
    }
}
```

`b.java`

```
public class b extends a {
    @Override
    public int the_func() {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The intended result of this code, if it worked, would be for the EntryPoint program to output "-1". Instead, an error is thrown because the class of a cannot be replaced with the class of b.

I'm not sure if this is a limitation in Java's design or if there is a way to seamlessly replace a class with another class, within that class based on a condition.

To add, the plugin system itself cannot be modified because no other plugins have a need to switch between 2 classes at run-time.

Comment: What you want to do is to define an interface and have subclasses that implement that interface. If you're using Spring, Boot makes this trivial; if you're not, SPI makes it manageable.

Comment: @chrylis I'll look into this, I specifically was trying to avoid using Interfaces for this because in the actual plugin system, there's an extend required for a class, and interfaces cannot extend classes.

Comment: You can still do this with classes, but in that case the plugin system is defective and *should* have been based around an interface.

Comment: @chrylis So here's the issue with that, the plugin system will instantiate anything defined as a plugin, and interfaces cannot be instantiated, so this is actually impossible because the objective is, based on some condition AFTER a class is instantiated, either use the methods from one or the other.

Comment: Also to add, this is an open source project known as RuneLite so you can view the plugin system for reference. Considering how big and widely used of an open source project this is, I don't think the plugin system is going to change.

Comment: `class implements Interface` and you'll be just fine. Some good old basic polymorphism

Comment: You really, really need to go through a basic Java tutorial. It's not uncommon at all to instantiate one or more classes that implement an interface and then invoke methods on them to select a specific implementation.

Comment: @WilomGfx Same issue, EntryPoint.java cannot be changed, and we cannot instantiate an interface.

Comment: @chrylis Similar issue with this, for a plugin we get 1 instantiation, so the question is still the same, how do we use that to select methods from one class, or another class.

Comment: In other words, we cannot change that System.out.println(new a().the_func()); is called, so how can a be internally rewired to allow for the functions to be called from either a or b, entirely separate from EntryPoint.java and contained within the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in Java due to the constant and final nature of classes, and it could easily confuse anyone who is used to C#/C++ which have these language features. I got around it. I ended up writing a plugin manager for the plugin manager specifically for choosing between and instantiating other classes. This isn't as graceful as I would have hoped, but it works. Here's the code, 'g.java' is the plugin manager for the plugin manager.

EntryPoint.java

```
public class EntryPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new g();
    }
}
```

a.java

```
public class a {
    public int the_func() {
        return 22;
    }
}
```

b.java

```
public class b extends a {
    @Override
    public int the_func() {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

g.java

```
// plugin loader simulation
public class g {
    public g() {
        System.out.println(new b().the_func());
    }
}
```